# Debug error: Heap corruption detected

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, pointers, malloc

I am playing around a bit in C and trying to write a test program for kind of oop in c programming. I get the Error of the headline in Visual Studio 2010. In using gcc i don't get this error.

Can anyone point me to what i am doing wrong, besides using the wrong language for oop, and other off topic suggestions.

It seems like the error occurs when i free the top object in string_dispose, but i am not shure if that really says a lot about the location of the error.

Also any suggestions regarding code improvements are welcome. Using array syntax is not an option, because i want to try out pointer arithmetic.

The header file "strings.h":

```
#ifndef STRINGS_H
#define STRINGS_H

struct strings
{
    char* s;
    int len;
};

typedef struct strings string;

void string_init(string* s, char* chars, int len);

string* string_new(char* chars, int len);

void string_dispose(string* s);

#endif
```

The source file "strings.c":

```
#include "strings.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


void string_init(string* self, char* chars, int len)
{
    int i;

    self->s = (char*)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *(self->s + i) = *(chars + i);
    }
    *(self->s + len) = '\0';
    self->len = len;
}


string* string_new(char* chars, int len)
{
    string* self;
    self = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string*));
    string_init(self, chars, len);
    return self;
}


void string_dispose(string* self)
{
    free(self->s);
    free(self);
}
```

The main file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "strings.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    string* s;
    int n = 5;
    char* x = (char*)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    x[0] = 'f';
    x[1] = 'u';
    x[2] = 'b';
    x[3] = 'a';
    x[4] = 'r';
    x[5] = '\0';
    s = string_new(x, n);   
    printf("the string: %s\n", s->s);
    printf("the length: %d\n", s->len);
    string_dispose(s);
    printf("This is way more important");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to allocate memory for `string`, you only allocate enough memory for a pointer (`string*`):

```
self = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string*));
```

You should allocate `sizeof(string)` instead, since you want enough space to store the whole struct, not just a pointer to one. Since `sizeof(string*)` is smaller than `sizeof(string)`, the other code writes outside of the allocated area, causing heap corruption.

Similarly, when mallocing memory for the characters, the size should be `(len + 1) * sizeof(char)`.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1, so just `(len + 1)` will be enough.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: It even will be too much and waste memory. It's the same mistake, just with less severe consequences.